# Reading graph in multinet

Tags: r, graph, social-networking

I found a new package in R that deals with multilayer networks called `multinet` and here's a link to it https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multinet/multinet.pdf.

I am trying to load my graph(csv file) using `read.ml` but an error pop out

```
net <- read.ml("test.csv")
```

> Error in read.ml("test.csv") :
>      Format error: Line 1: unrecognized statement`

Any advice on how to solve it?

Test data set:

```
a  b  
a  c  
b  c
```

Where "a b" means there is an edge between person a and person b

Comment: Is the form of your file consistent with what is described in the help file? Can you show the first 5 lines of the text file that has your graph? thanks

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: Thanks for the update Hina. Your data just looks like a regular edgelist - (from -> to) - one that after reading in would be a regular graph. The form does not seem consistent what is described in the multinet doc you link to. For an example of what a file may look like, the docs have an example: `library(multinet) ;file <- tempfile() ;net <- ml.aucs() ;write.ml(net,file) ; cat(readLines(file), sep="\n")` (caveat ive not used multinet before)

Comment: Is it possible to modify my data so that it is readable for multinet?

Comment: I dont know, but the data you show doesnt seems to have layers / hierarchies